# Delete a document from firebase collection

Tags: flutter, delete-file

I am working on a simple booking application.
For each booked slot I have a Cancel button, when pressed the appointment should be deleted from the collection.

```
  Future deleteAppt() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("client_bookings").get();

    for (int i = 0; i < querySnapshot.docs.length; i++) {
      var a = querySnapshot.docs[i];

      final collection =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('client_bookings');
      collection
          .doc(a.id) // <-- Doc ID to be deleted.
          .delete() // <-- Delete
          .then((_) => print('Deleted'))
          .catchError((error) => print('Delete failed: $error'));

      print(a.id);
    }
  }
```

This is my code so far. However, when the button is clicked all appointments are deleted. Could you give me any advice how can i fix this?
In addition, I am using a StreamBuilder and ListView.builder to iterate though the collection and display each appointment in a container.

[scheme image added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzoe5.png)

```
StreamBuilder(
                          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('client_bookings')
                              .where("email",
                              isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email)
                              .snapshots(),
                          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              print(snapshot.hasData);
                              return Text("error");
                            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                              print(snapshot.hasData);
                              return ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
                                    var data = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                                    var bookingStart = data['bookingStart'];
                                    DateTime bookingStartConverted = DateTime.parse(bookingStart);
                                    
                                    if(bookingStartConverted.isAfter(today)) {
                                      print("upcoming");
                                      return Container(
                                        height: height,
                                        width: width,
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                                20),
                                            boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(
                                                  color: Colors.blueGrey
                                                      .shade100,
                                                  blurRadius: 5,
                                                  spreadRadius: 3)
                                            ]),
                                        child: Align(
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            child: Column(children: [
                                              Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                  EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      left: 15, top: 8),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    "Dr. " + data['doctorName'],
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 17,
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight
                                                            .bold,
                                                        color: Colors
                                                            .blueAccent),
                                                  )),
                                              Padding(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: 5),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    data['doctorType'],
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 15,
                                                        color: Colors.grey),
                                                  )),
                                              const Divider(
                                                height: 22,
                                                thickness: 0.4,
                                                color: Colors.grey,
                                              ),
                                              Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Icon(Icons
                                                      .access_time_outlined),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                      flex: 1,
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        data['bookingStart'],
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 16,
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .black87
                                                                .withOpacity(
                                                                0.5)),
                                                      )),
                                                  Icon(Icons
                                                      .location_on_outlined),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    flex: 1,
                                                    child: TextButton(
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          opentApptMap();
                                                        },
                                                        child: Text(
                                                          data['hospitalName'],
                                                          textAlign: TextAlign
                                                              .center,
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              decoration: TextDecoration
                                                                  .underline),
                                                        )),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: 5.0),
                                                  child: Row(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      Expanded(
                                                        child: SizedBox(
                                                          // width: 80,
                                                          height: 30,
                                                          child: ElevatedButton(
                                                            child: const Text(
                                                                "Cancel"),
                                                            onPressed: () {
                                                              Navigator.of(
                                                                  context).push(
                                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                                      builder: (
                                                                          context) =>
                                                                          CancelApptBox()));
                                                            },
                                                            style:
                                                            ElevatedButton
                                                                .styleFrom(
                                                                shape:
                                                                StadiumBorder(),
                                                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                                  fontSize: 15,
                                                                )),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      Padding(
                                                          padding:
                                                          EdgeInsets.only(
                                                              right: 8)),
                                                      Expanded(
                                                        child: SizedBox(
                                                          // width: 80,
                                                          height: 30,
                                                          child: ElevatedButton(
                                                            child:
                                                            const Text(
                                                                "Reschedule"),
                                                            onPressed: () {},
                                                            style:
                                                            ElevatedButton
                                                                .styleFrom(
                                                                shape:
                                                                StadiumBorder(),
                                                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                                  fontSize: 15,
                                                                )),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  ))
                                            ])),
                                      );
                                    }else{
                                      print("no appts");
                                    }
                                  });
                            } else {
                              return Text("else");
                            }
                          })
```

//Cancel appt Box

```
class CancelApptBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const CancelApptBox({super.key});

  Future deleteAppt() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("client_bookings").get();

    for (int i = 0; i < querySnapshot.docs.length; i++) {
      var a = querySnapshot.docs[i];

      final collection =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('client_bookings');
      collection
          .doc(a.id) // <-- Doc ID to be deleted.
          .delete() // <-- Delete
          .then((_) => print('Deleted'))
          .catchError((error) => print('Delete failed: $error'));

      print(a.id);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Are you sure you want to cancel the appointment?'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, 'Yes');
            deleteAppt();
          },
          child: const Text('Yes',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Go back'),
          child: const Text('Go back'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: error in the main page]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete a specific appointment, you should pass appointment id.

```dart
Future<void> deleteAppt(String apptId) async {
  final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('client_bookings');
  try {
    await collection.doc(apptId).delete();
    print('Deleted');
  } catch (error) {
    print('Delete failed: $error');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are iterating  over every document and deleting that document

```
 for (int i = 0; i < querySnapshot.docs.length; i++) {}
```

remove the for statement

cancel button

```
class CancelApptBox extends StatelessWidget {
int i;
  const CancelApptBox({super.key,}this.i);

  Future deleteAppt() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("client_bookings").get();


      var a = querySnapshot.docs[i];

      final collection =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('client_bookings');
      collection
          .doc(a.id) // <-- Doc ID to be deleted.
          .delete() // <-- Delete
          .then((_) => print('Deleted'))
          .catchError((error) => print('Delete failed: $error'));

      print(a.id);
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Are you sure you want to cancel the appointment?'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, 'Yes');
            deleteAppt();
          },
          child: const Text('Yes',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Go back'),
          child: const Text('Go back'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

main page

```
StreamBuilder(
                          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('client_bookings')
                              .where("email",
                              isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email)
                              .snapshots(),
                          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              print(snapshot.hasData);
                              return Text("error");
                            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                              print(snapshot.hasData);
                              return ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
                                    var data = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                                    var bookingStart = data['bookingStart'];
                                    DateTime bookingStartConverted = DateTime.parse(bookingStart);
                                    
                                    if(bookingStartConverted.isAfter(today)) {
                                      print("upcoming");
                                      return Container(
                                        height: height,
                                        width: width,
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                                20),
                                            boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(
                                                  color: Colors.blueGrey
                                                      .shade100,
                                                  blurRadius: 5,
                                                  spreadRadius: 3)
                                            ]),
                                        child: Align(
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            child: Column(children: [
                                              Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                  EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      left: 15, top: 8),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    "Dr. " + data['doctorName'],
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 17,
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight
                                                            .bold,
                                                        color: Colors
                                                            .blueAccent),
                                                  )),
                                              Padding(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: 5),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    data['doctorType'],
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 15,
                                                        color: Colors.grey),
                                                  )),
                                              const Divider(
                                                height: 22,
                                                thickness: 0.4,
                                                color: Colors.grey,
                                              ),
                                              Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Icon(Icons
                                                      .access_time_outlined),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                      flex: 1,
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        data['bookingStart'],
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 16,
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .black87
                                                                .withOpacity(
                                                                0.5)),
                                                      )),
                                                  Icon(Icons
                                                      .location_on_outlined),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    flex: 1,
                                                    child: TextButton(
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          opentApptMap();
                                                        },
                                                        child: Text(
                                                          data['hospitalName'],
                                                          textAlign: TextAlign
                                                              .center,
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              decoration: TextDecoration
                                                                  .underline),
                                                        )),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      top: 5.0),
                                                  child: Row(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      Expanded(
                                                        child: SizedBox(
                                                          // width: 80,
                                                          height: 30,
                                                          child: ElevatedButton(
                                                            child: const Text(
                                                                "Cancel"),
                                                            onPressed: () {
                                                              Navigator.of(
                                                                  context).push(
                                                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                                                      builder: (
                                                                          context) =>
                                                                          CancelApptBox(i)));
                                                            },
                                                            style:
                                                            ElevatedButton
                                                                .styleFrom(
                                                                shape:
                                                                StadiumBorder(),
                                                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                                  fontSize: 15,
                                                                )),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      Padding(
                                                          padding:
                                                          EdgeInsets.only(
                                                              right: 8)),
                                                      Expanded(
                                                        child: SizedBox(
                                                          // width: 80,
                                                          height: 30,
                                                          child: ElevatedButton(
                                                            child:
                                                            const Text(
                                                                "Reschedule"),
                                                            onPressed: () {},
                                                            style:
                                                            ElevatedButton
                                                                .styleFrom(
                                                                shape:
                                                                StadiumBorder(),
                                                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                                  fontSize: 15,
                                                                )),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  ))
                                            ])),
                                      );
                                    }else{
                                      print("no appts");
                                    }
                                  });
                            } else {
                              return Text("else");
                            }
                          })
```

Comment: then how i will access that particular file i want to delete(the one that user is clicked on to be deleted)

Comment: you have to get the id of the document and delete it

Comment: i am not storing the id inside the collection, i added a scheme image in my question. Is it possible to extract the id generated by firebase?

Comment: can you share the code of your complete slot

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by complete slot?

Comment: you have written `for each booked slot ` i mean the whole code of it

Comment: question is updated

Comment: your document id the variable `i` just pass that to the delete function and  delete it

Comment: when i pass it all documents are deleted

Comment: can you show me where are you calling `deleteAppt`

Comment: i updated my code, this is a small dialog box which is displayed when the user clicks on the cancel btn

Comment: i have updated the code, check if it works

Comment: i added a screenshot of the error in the main page

Comment: it should be fixed now check it again ,there was just a small mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a specific value from a collection, you must provide the document id that you want to delete.In above snippet you are providing all document id to delete method.That's why all docs are being removed from collection.

If you want to delete a specific item, follow the steps below.
1)Get whole collection.
2)Find the id from collection that you want to delete.
3)Pass that id to delete method.

Note:If you already have an ID that needs to be deleted, ignore the "First" point.